# While iterating through an array, how to make sure that the correct output is printed?

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

I am making a simple C program that takes a user input and checks if it is a valid password from an array. I am finding though that if it is the last password in the array (if there are 7 valid passwords) and I am using an if statement to iterate through each element in the array to check for validity, it prints "access denied" until the correct password is reached because it is not one of the first few allowed passwords.

Here's what I have:

```
int userPass = 1971;
int validPass [] = {1912, 1914, 1922, 1947, 1958, 1964, 1971};
int i = 0;

while (validPass[i])
{
    if (userPass == validPass[i])
        {
            printf("Access granted \n");
        }
    else
        {
            printf("Access denied \n");
        }
   i++;
}
```

This printed 'access denied' 6 times then on the 7th time it prints 'access granted' because it the user password is correct as per the 7th element within the array. How can I get it to check each element for validity before printing access granted or denied, to ensure that even if it is the last element in the array the correct line will print? I tried moving my i++ to before the else statement and within the if statement, but the program did not like that.

Comment: Your `while` line doesn't have a good way of stopping -- once you go through all the `validPass` entries (#0-6), `i` will be 7, and the program will just keep going.  It's not clear what the program will find after valid password 1971, but the program won't stop until it runs into a 0 somewhere after 1971.  That may or may not ever happen, and for your purposes, you can assume that those numbers are essentially random.  What happens if one of those random numbers matches `userPass`?  You'll get "Access granted," which may not be what you expect.

Comment: Note that your code uses undefined behaviour to terminate the *while* clause. I guess you come from a JavaScript or other background, where accessing an out of bound index will returns `undefined`. However in C this is not the case and accessing an index out of bounds will yield undefined behaviour and return the bytes after the array (when accessible) interpreted as integer in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loop through the options don't print anything yet.  If you find the correct value set a flag.  Then print the text based on the value of the flag.

```
int found = 0;
while (i<(sizeof(validPass)/sizeof(validPass[0])) {
    if (userPass == validPass[i]) {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

if (found) {
    printf("Access granted \n");
} else {
    printf("Access denied \n");
}
```

Comment: I would include `int i = 0;` in your snippet